# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is my first time working with react js , im trying to remove the alert when leaving this view cause i don't want to show it on the other view but in case that there is no error i want to keep the success alert to show it when i'm gonna redirect to the other view

but im getting this wearning on google chrome 
`Line 97:6:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

if i did include dispatch i get infinite loop

```
const [state, dispatch] = useUserStore();
useEffect(() => {
    let token = params.params.token;
    checktoken(token, dispatch);
  }, [params.params.token]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (state.alert.msg === "Error") {
        dispatch({
          type: REMOVE_ALERT
        });
      }
    };
  }, [state.alert.msg]);

//response from the api
if (!token_valide || token_valide_message === "done") {
      return <Redirect to="/login" />;
    }
```

this is useUserStore

```
  const globalReducers = useCombinedReducers({
    alert: useReducer(alertReducer, alertInitState),
    auth: useReducer(authReducer, authInitState),
    register: useReducer(registerReducer, registerInitState),
    token: useReducer(passeditReducer, tokenvalidationInitState)
  });
  return (
    <appStore.Provider value={globalReducers}>{children}</appStore.Provider>
  );
};

export const useUserStore = () => useContext(appStore);
```

Comment: What is `useUserStore`?

Comment: @Dupocas Op already tried that but then gets infinite loop.

Comment: Updated the answer. Wrap it in an `useCallback` and pass this wrapped version to your effect

Comment: Now we have to ask what is useCombineRecurs.

Comment: useCombineRecurs is a library similar to CombineReducers in redux

Comment: Ok, so it's [this one](https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/use-combined-reducers)?

Comment: @HMR yes exactly it is

Comment: You can try to not create globalReducers every time so useCombineReducers won't return a new dispatch every time.

Comment: @HMR Im gonna look for that thank you

Comment: Already figured out you can't fix it that way. Problem is with the useCombinedReducers, posted an answer but when I've got time I will send them a pull request.

Comment: @BukLau Updated answer, created issue and [pull request](https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/use-combined-reducers/issues/4) for useCombinedReducers

Comment: @HMR thank you for your help im gonna look for the pull request

Comment: the [doc](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) said that "The simplest solution is to do just that"

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### UPDATE 09/11/2020

This solution is no longer needed on `eslint-plugin-react-hooks@4.1.0` and above.

Now `useMemo` and `useCallback` can safely receive referential types as dependencies.[#19590](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/19590)

```
function MyComponent() {
  const foo = ['a', 'b', 'c']; // <== This array is reconstructed each render
  const normalizedFoo = useMemo(() => foo.map(expensiveMapper), [foo]);
  return <OtherComponent foo={normalizedFoo} />
}
```

Here is another example of how to safely stabilize(normalize) a callback

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('Greetings!')

    return (
        <h3>
            { message }
        </h3>
        <Child setter={setMessage} />
    )
}

const Child = ({
    setter
}) => {
    const stableSetter = useCallback(args => {
        console.log('Only firing on mount!')
        return setter(args)
    }, [setter])

    useEffect(() => {
        stableSetter('Greetings from child\'s mount cycle')
    }, [stableSetter]) //now shut up eslint

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    const add = () => setCount(c => c + 1)

    return (
        <button onClick={add}>
            Rerender {count}
        </button>
    )
}
```

Now referential types with stable signature such as those provenients from `useState` or `useDispatch` can safely be used inside an effect without triggering `exhaustive-deps` even when coming from `props`

[image: Edit silly-andras-9v1yp]

---

### Old answer

`dispatch` comes from a custom `hook` so it doesn't have an stable signature therefore will change on each render (reference equality). Add an aditional layer of dependencies by wrapping the handler inside an `useCallback` hook

```
   const [foo, dispatch] = myCustomHook()
  
   const stableDispatch = useCallback(dispatch, []) //assuming that it doesn't need to change

   useEffect(() =>{
        stableDispatch(foo)
   },[stableDispatch])
```

---

`useCallback` and `useMemo` are helper hooks with the main purpose off adding an extra layer of **dependency check** to ensure synchronicity. Usually you want to work with `useCallback` to ensure a stable signature to a `prop` that you know how will change and React doesn't.

A `function`(reference type) passed via `props` for example

```
const Component = ({ setParentState }) =>{
    useEffect(() => setParentState('mounted'), [])
}
```

Lets assume you have a child component which uppon mounting must set some state in the parent (not usual), the above code will generate a warning of undeclared dependency in `useEffect`, so let's declare `setParentState` as a dependency to be checked by React

```
const Component = ({ setParentState }) =>{
    useEffect(() => setParentState('mounted'), [setParentState])
}
```

Now this effect runs on each render, not only on mounting, but on each update. This happens because `setParentState` is a `function` which is recreated every time the function `Component` gets called. You know that `setParentState` won't change it's signature overtime so it's safe to tell React that. By wrapping the original helper inside an `useCallback` you're doing exactly that (adding another dependency check layer).

```
const Component = ({ setParentState }) =>{
   const stableSetter = useCallback(() => setParentState(), [])

   useEffect(() => setParentState('mounted'), [stableSetter])
}
```

There you go. Now `React` knows that `stableSetter` won't change it's signature inside the lifecycle therefore the effect do not need too run unecessarily.

On a side note `useCallback` it's also used like `useMemo`, to optmize expensive function calls (memoization).

The two mai/n purposes of `useCallback` are

- Optimize child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary
  renders. [Font](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)
- Memoize expensive calculations

Comment: Will work but I think OP should solve it at the source not where OP is going to use dispatch which may be in many places.

Comment: Even if he wraps `dispatch` with an `useCallback` inside `customHook` the problem will persist, and `useUserStore` doesn't seen to be a hook that he can actually change the source code.

Comment: I don't know the useCombinedReducers library but it may be fixed by `useCombinedReducers(not passing new ref every time)`

Comment: I don't know it either. If he can then sure it's a better solution than wrap it inside an `useCallback` everytime.

Comment: @Dupocas your solution work fine for me thank you for your help, Im not using redux actually Im new to this framework

Comment: Solving at the root would be difficult because the root [combines state with dispatch](https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/use-combined-reducers/blob/master/src/index.js) when state changes then so will dispatch. This is not how React.useReducer works and I think it's not how that library should work either.

Comment: I do not think this is necessary. Being a custom hook doesn't change anything. 
> React guarantees that dispatch function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list.
This is from the docs.

Comment: Yeap, this is an old issue that no longer exists on newer versions of `eslint`. But trust me, it was a problem back then...

Comment: For me eslint still warns about missing dependency `dispatch`, although it's on a new version

Answer (score 2):

I think you can solve the problem at the root but that means changing useCombinedReducers, I forked the repo and created [a pull request](https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/use-combined-reducers/pull/5) because I don't think useCombinedReducers should return a new reference for dispatch every time you call it.

```
function memoize(fn) {
  let lastResult,
    //initial last arguments is not going to be the same
    //  as anything you will pass to the function the first time
    lastArguments = [{}];
  return (...currentArgs) => {
    //returning memoized function
    //check if currently passed arguments are the same as
    //  arguments passed last time
    const sameArgs =
      currentArgs.length === lastArguments.length &&
      lastArguments.reduce(
        (result, lastArg, index) =>
          result && Object.is(lastArg, currentArgs[index]),
        true,
      );
    if (sameArgs) {
      //current arguments are same as last so just
      //  return the last result and don't execute function
      return lastResult;
    }
    //current arguments are not the same as last time
    //  or function called for the first time, execute the
    //  function and set last result
    lastResult = fn.apply(null, currentArgs);
    //set last args to current args
    lastArguments = currentArgs;
    //return result
    return lastResult;
  };
}

const createDispatch = memoize((...dispatchers) => action =>
  dispatchers.forEach(fn => fn(action)),
);
const createState = memoize(combinedReducers =>
  Object.keys(combinedReducers).reduce(
    (acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: combinedReducers[key][0] }),
    {},
  ),
);
const useCombinedReducers = combinedReducers => {
  // Global State
  const state = createState(combinedReducers);

  const dispatchers = Object.values(combinedReducers).map(
    ([, dispatch]) => dispatch,
  );

  // Global Dispatch Function
  const dispatch = createDispatch(...dispatchers);

  return [state, dispatch];
};

export default useCombinedReducers;
```

Here is a working example:

```js
const reduceA = (state, { type }) =>
  type === 'a' ? { count: state.count + 1 } : state;
const reduceC = (state, { type }) =>
  type === 'c' ? { count: state.count + 1 } : state;
const state = { count: 1 };
function App() {
  const [a, b] = React.useReducer(reduceA, state);
  const [c, d] = React.useReducer(reduceC, state);
  //memoize what is passed to useCombineReducers
  const obj = React.useMemo(
    () => ({ a: [a, b], c: [c, d] }),
    [a, b, c, d]
  );
  //does not do anything with reduced state
  const [, reRender] = React.useState();
  const [s, dispatch] = useCombinedReducers(obj);
  const rendered = React.useRef(0);
  const [sc, setSc] = React.useState(0);
  const [dc, setDc] = React.useState(0);
  rendered.current++;//display how many times this is rendered
  React.useEffect(() => {//how many times state changed
    setSc(x => x + 1);
  }, [s]);
  React.useEffect(() => {//how many times dispatch changed
    setDc(x => x + 1);
  }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>rendered {rendered.current} times</div>
      <div>state changed {sc} times</div>
      <div>dispatch changed {dc} times</div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => reRender({})}>
        re render
      </button>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'a' })}
      >
        change a
      </button>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'c' })}
      >
        change c
      </button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(s, undefined, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

function memoize(fn) {
  let lastResult,
    //initial last arguments is not going to be the same
    //  as anything you will pass to the function the first time
    lastArguments = [{}];
  return (...currentArgs) => {
    //returning memoized function
    //check if currently passed arguments are the same as
    //  arguments passed last time
    const sameArgs =
      currentArgs.length === lastArguments.length &&
      lastArguments.reduce(
        (result, lastArg, index) =>
          result && Object.is(lastArg, currentArgs[index]),
        true
      );
    if (sameArgs) {
      //current arguments are same as last so just
      //  return the last result and don't execute function
      return lastResult;
    }
    //current arguments are not the same as last time
    //  or function called for the first time, execute the
    //  function and set last result
    lastResult = fn.apply(null, currentArgs);
    //set last args to current args
    lastArguments = currentArgs;
    //return result
    return lastResult;
  };
}

const createDispatch = memoize((...dispatchers) => action =>
  dispatchers.forEach(fn => fn(action))
);
const createState = memoize(combinedReducers =>
  Object.keys(combinedReducers).reduce(
    (acc, key) => ({
      ...acc,
      [key]: combinedReducers[key][0],
    }),
    {}
  )
);
const useCombinedReducers = combinedReducers => {
  // Global State
  const state = createState(combinedReducers);

  const dispatchers = Object.values(combinedReducers).map(
    ([, dispatch]) => dispatch
  );

  // Global Dispatch Function
  const dispatch = createDispatch(...dispatchers);

  return [state, dispatch];
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help im gonna try it