# Why am I getting an infinite loop inside the component as state is globally managed?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

I'm working with redux saga and redux toolkit. In the `EachUser` component, I don't understand why the component is mounting over and over again if I don't use the `useEffect` hook. Could someone help me understand why it is.

I'm not changing any props or state so I don't think infinite loop should happen but it is happening.

Here is the link to my code sandbox: [Redux Saga With Redux toolkit](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-and-redux-saga-forked-oc272?file=/src/EachUser.js)

Comment: I saw code sandbox work fine. What is your problem?

Comment: No, it works fine with useEffect but I don;t understand why useEffect is required. Without useEffect it's going into an infinite loop.

Comment: If you don't use `useEffect`, Where do you dispach action FETCH_SINGLE_USER?

Comment: So we can't dispatch right as the component is being mounted? I'm sorry I'm really new to redux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happens following:

When you are trying to dispatch your `FETCH_SINGLE_USER` action on the top level of your functional component it will be executed on each render cycle (your function is re-rendered(executed) each time when props or state changed, also it will be re-rendered when the parent component is re-rendered (if you don't use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)).
So when you are dispatching your action on the top level of your functional component it will

```
fetch user from the server 
->
update your store
->
updated store will cause re-render of the component as you are selecting updated state with useSelector
-> 
fetch user from the server action dispatched again (we are inside of the infinite loop)
```

So why we need useEffect - it is the hook that helps us to make some actions on special conditions. In the second parameter, you should put an array of dependencies, once dependency changed it will cause hook rerun. If the array is empty - hook will be executed only once when your functional component mounted. Also you can return cleanup function that will be executed, once your component unmounted. More documentation on useEffect hook [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: I think you meant updated state with useSelector instead of useState, right?

Comment: Right, fixed answer

Answer (score 1):

try to remove *dispatch* from the array of dependencies

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: sagaActions.FETCH_SINGLE_USER, userId });
  }, [userId]);
```

calling a function inside *useEffect* and specifying it in an array of dependencies can cause an infinite rerender

Comment: As I understand, dispatch shouldn't cause re-rendering see related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624200/react-hook-useeffect-has-a-missing-dependency-dispatch)

Comment: Probably still causes, as I understood from the answer to the question - dispatch comes from a custom hook so it doesn't have an stable signature therefore will change on each render (reference equality). Add an aditional layer of dependencies by wrapping the handler inside an useCallback hook
const stableDispatch = useCallback(dispatch, [])

Comment: You can check code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-and-redux-saga-forked-oc272?file=/src/EachUser.js) and re-rendering happen only when useEffect not there