# useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, warnings, dispatch

I am using Reactjs and Redux.

```
//constants
const dispatch = useDispatch();

//useEffects
useEffect(() => {
  if (!IsEmpty(loggedUser)) {
    dispatch(actions.getUserDetail({ userId: loggedUser.Sid }));
  }
}, [loggedUser]);
```

Everything is working fine. But I am getting a warning in browser's console :

> src/components/EditProfile.js
> Line 91:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I don't know how can I remove this warning.
Please help me !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624200/react-hook-useeffect-has-a-missing-dependency-dispatch)

Comment: Some are saying, you can add`dispatch` as dependency array in `useEffect`. Is it safe ?

Comment: @JohnLobo The link you provided, is not my answer. Because If I use `useCallback` and move dispatch inside that useCallback then I am getting the same warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove `warnings` like `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'` then you can use `eslint-disable-next-line` in your `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!IsEmpty(loggedUser)) {
    dispatch(actions.getUserDetail({ userId: loggedUser.Sid }));
  }
  //eslint-disable-next-line
}, [loggedUser]);
```

Comment: Some are saying, you can add dispatch as dependency array in useEffect. Is it safe ?

Comment: You can add it if you want  but sometimes it can cause `infinite loop`. You can check if that happens in your case if doesn't then it's alright you can add `dispatch` to the `dependency array`

Comment: No issue. Currently, I am using `//eslint-disable-next-line`

Comment: whatever makes your code work bro!

Comment: `//eslint-disable-next-line` this is simple. Because I don't want to add dispatch as a dependency array on every file where I have used useEffect and check for infinite loop in every file.

Comment: that's a good point. But `dispatch` rarely causes `infinite loop` but in the end it depends on your choice either one is fine.