# Why include external functions in dependency array in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not entirely clear why we need to include all* dependencies for useEffect

For example

```
import { apiCall } from 'api'; 

const App = () => {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        apiCall(); 
    }, [])
    
    return <p>hi</p>

}
```

As I understand it, this is wrong. I should include `apiCall` in the dependency array. I'm just not quite clear why that's necessary? I only want this to run once, when the component mounts. Why do I need to include any other information?

Comment: You don't have to, it's just *recommended* by some (and not preferred by others)

Comment: IIRC this has also been somewhat mitigated lately. In any case, exhaustive-deps is meant to target component variables, not external ones. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/56972415/438992 for some details and the update (I haven't dug into it yet).

Comment: It is not necessary. The [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) mentions that _"function outside of your component is guaranteed to not reference any props or state, and also doesn’t need to be in the list of dependencies."_