# useEffect hook in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

My useEffect hook is running when dependency has not changed.

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log('Search useEffect Run')
   dispatch(fetchSearchData(searchItem));          
 }, [dispatch, searchItem]);
```

searchItem is part of a Redux slice as:

const searchItem = useSelector((state) => state.posts.searchTerm);

const initialState = {
posts: [],
searchTerm: '',
selectedSubreddit: 'r/pics/',
};

The useEffect is running when searchItem is not changing from empty string.

Thanks for any help.

I have tried useCallback but getting the same issue.

This is inside a function and useEffect runs twice each time function is rendered (for a unrelated event).

Cheers

Comment: You don't have to add `dispatch` to the dependency array, the function won't change.

Comment: If I do not add dispatch as a dependency it gives me a warning as:
    React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Comment: Yes, the linter warning is famously wrong/overzealous in this case. See updated answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56972415/useeffect-dependency-array-and-eslint-exhaustive-deps-rule

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are in useStrict mode.
useStrict make your useEffect hook runs twice for debugging purpose
read more about [useStrict](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode)

Comment: Cheers. It runs twice on first render, then runs twice each time the function renders even though the dependency not changing. Could it be something to do with it being part of a Redux slice